# Segue from tab view controller

Tags: swift, swift3, segue

I am trying to segue from a tab view controller into a view controller. The segue is present modally. The code is below:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if (UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "HasLaunchedOnce")) {
        print("LAnched B4")
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "Tutorial", sender: nil)
    } else {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "HasLaunchedOnce")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "Tutorial", sender: nil)
    } 
}
```

The problem I'm having is that there is no segue that happens, the first view controller on the tab bar is shown first. Is there a way to prioritise the segue?

Comment: add a segue from the viewController that is presented first not from the TabBarController

Answer (score 1):

> Yes Follow below code for achieving your task you just need to add the below function in your controller

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Tutorial" {
        print("INSIDE TAB")
        if let tabVC = segue.destination as? UITabBarController{
            if !User().getIsLoggedIn() {
                print("INSIDE")
                tabVC.selectedIndex = 2 // Or you can give your viewController index
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Remember these index will start from `0` to the last. so according to your requirement check your segue condition and prepare that segue for the desired index.